# Configure OS X Terminal to detect URLs and make them clickable?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to configure OS X Terminal to detect text that looks like URLs, and make them clickable?  Where "clickable" means, clicking will open a web browser on the *local/client* machine?

> Example use case: Connect with SSH to my own remote host running non-GUI-desktop Linux. Read email in mutt (or whatever) that is running on the server. But when an email contains a URL, be able to open it *locally*, in a GUI browser.
>
> In other words, use the terminal and SSH as the client for texty things on my own remote server -- but use a local web browser as the client for browsing the web on N servers. (I don't want to VNC to a remote GUI where a browser is running; I think that would be silly.)
>
> > This is one big flaw in my idea of ditching Gmail and keeping all email only on my own server (not even downloading to a local mail client): So much of my email consists of links to click.

If the answer entails using a terminal app other than the one provided with OS X, I'm open to trying that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily open any URL directly in the Terminal-app.

**OSX-versions before Lion:**

`cmd+shift+double-click` a URL and it will open.

**OSX Lion/Moutain Lion:**

`cmd+double-click`

Answer (score 1):

On [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/), it is simply: `cmd+click` (convenient, as the cmd key will highlight and underline the link).